# How the kernel enters kdb mode by sysrq-g?

Tags: linux, serial-port, gdb, kgdb

Can someone suggest how the kernel hangs while entering kdb mode using the command 
`echo g > /proc/sysrq-trigger` .How kgdb and kdb differs?

Is there any process running when the kernel enters debugger mode?.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has the answer :-), it "halts kernel" hence kernel is frozen until you allow it run from gdb on the host.

refer following doc for further info.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kgdb.html